# Find key inside a multiple level object

Tags: javascript, object, search, find

my backend build this object:

```
{
  "cats": {
    "persian": {
      "19:51:38": {
        "name": "Perry"
      },
      "19:51:40": {
        "name": "Bob",
      }
      "19:51:39": {
        "name": "Saurus",
      },
    },
    "ragdoll": {
      "19:51:38": {
        "name": "Billy",
      },
      "19:51:43": {
        "name": "Billy",
      }
      "19:51:39": {
        "name": "Pepi",
      },
    },
    "norwegian": {
      "19:51:34": {
        "name": "Michonne",
      },
      "19:52:40": {
        "name": "Bull",
      },
      "19:52:42": {
        "name": "Oscar",
      }
    }
  },
  "dogs": {
    "labrador": {
      "19:51:35": {
        "name": "Alice",
      },
      "19:51:36": {
        "name": "Arthur",
      },
      "19:51:37": {
        "name": "Nemo",
      },
      "19:51:40": {
        "name": "Rose",
      }
    },
    "chihuahua": {
      "19:51:35": {
        "name": "Dory",
      },
      "19:51:36": {
        "name": "Bob",
      },
      "19:51:37": {
        "name": "Carl",
      },
      "19:51:38": {
        "name": "Bruce",
      },
      "19:51:39": {
        "name": "Moon",
      }
    },
    "pomeranian": {
      "19:51:35": {
        "name": "Elvis",
      },
      "19:51:36": {
        "name": "Dorian",
      },
      "19:51:37": {
        "name": "Amy",
      },
      "19:51:38": {
        "name": "Bill",
      }
    },
    "collie": {
      "19:51:35": {
        "name": "Thaurus",
      },
      "19:51:37": {
        "name": "Mine",
      },
      "19:51:40": {
        "name": "Wyng",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a search field that allows you to insert a date hour in this format `hh:mm:ss`.

Now I want to return the object associated with that date. I do an example: if the user searches for `19:51:40`, the application must return this array of objects:

`[{type: "cats", breed: "persian", name: "Bob"}, {type: "dogs", breed: "labrador", name: "Rose"}, , {type: "dogs", breed: "collie", name: "Wyng"}]`

I thought about doing this by doing a for loop that checks every key *hour*. Is this the fastest method? I don't believe...

In lodash is there a method call `findKey` but I can not use it because I don't know the name of the key (the one related to the breed), it changes. 
So how do I do a search?

Answer (score 0):

you can use nested for loops to iterate over the keys, and get the desired result :

```js
let obj = { "cats": { "persian": { "19:51:38": { "name": "Perry" }, "19:51:40": { "name": "Bob" }, "19:51:39": { "name": "Saurus" } }, "ragdoll": { "19:51:38": { "name": "Billy" }, "19:51:43": { "name": "Billy" }, "19:51:39": { "name": "Pepi" }, }, "norwegian": { "19:51:34": { "name": "Michonne" }, "19:52:40": { "name": "Bull" }, "19:52:42": { "name": "Oscar" } } }, "dogs": { "labrador": { "19:51:35": { "name": "Alice" }, "19:51:36": { "name": "Arthur" }, "19:51:37": { "name": "Nemo" }, "19:51:40": { "name": "Rose" } }, "chihuahua": { "19:51:35": { "name": "Dory" }, "19:51:36": { "name": "Bob" }, "19:51:37": { "name": "Carl" }, "19:51:38": { "name": "Bruce" }, "19:51:39": { "name": "Moon" } }, "pomeranian": { "19:51:35": { "name": "Elvis" }, "19:51:36": { "name": "Dorian" }, "19:51:37": { "name": "Amy" }, "19:51:38": { "name": "Bill" } }, "collie": { "19:51:35": { "name": "Thaurus"}, "19:51:37": { "name": "Mine" }, "19:51:40": { "name": "Wyng" } } } };

function search(obj, t){
let result = [];
  for(type in obj){
    for(breed in obj[type]){
      for(time in obj[type][breed]){
          if(time === t){
            result.push({type,breed, name : obj[type][breed][time].name})
          }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(search(obj, "19:51:40"));
```